# Add a prefix to mutliple elements from the parent attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to add a unique prefix to ID's and other reference links.

I have multiple identical SVGs on a page. These SVGs serve as a wrapper (they're devices - laptop, phone, etc.) which have image link that is inserted into the SVG after load. The problem is, the ID's for these svgs are identical so they all conflict with each other. What I'm trying to do (but am open to better solutions) is to insert a unique ID to each `id`,`xlink:href`, `url(#`, etc. but pass over the `<image>` `href` attribute and `fill` and `stroke` attributes.

**EDIT**: I added/tweaked the code provided by @Temani, which got me closer to my desired result, however, I'm now getting all the ID's added to each SVG element. Formatted the code to be executable.

**Desired output:**

```
<div class="device" data-screen="[[IMAGE TO USE]]" data-name"[[UNIQUE ID]]">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="635" height="420" viewBox="0 0 635 420">
    <defs>
      <path id="[[UNIQUE ID]]-path-1"/>
      <rect id="[[UNIQUE ID]]-path-3" />
      <pattern id="[[UNIQUE ID]]-pattern-4">
        <use transform="scale(13.1875)" xlink:href="#[[UNIQUE ID]]-image-5"/>
      </pattern>
      <image id="[[UNIQUE ID]]-image-5" href="[[IMAGE LINK THAT IS INSERTED AFTER LOAD]]"/>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#2D8EFF" />
      <g >
        <mask id="[[UNIQUE ID]]-mask-2" fill="#fff">
          <use xlink:href="#[[UNIQUE ID]]-path-1"/>
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#[[UNIQUE ID]]-mask-2)">
          <mask id="mask-6" fill="#fff">
            <use xlink:href="#[[UNIQUE ID]]-path-3"/>
          </mask>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Right now - both ID's (first and second) gets added to each SVG element. I also

```js
$('.device').each(function() {
     //we get the needed id using $(this) that refer to actual device
     var id = $(this).data('name');

    //we check all the element with ID
    $(this).find("path, rect, pattern, image, mask").each(function() {
      //now (this) refer to the actual element
      if($(this).attr("id"))
        $(this).attr("id", id+"-"+$(this).attr("id"));
    });
    //we update the <use>
     $(this).find("use").each(function() {
      //now (this) refer to the actual element
     $(this).attr("xlink:href","#"+id+"-"+$(this).attr("xlink:href").substring(1));
    });
    

// Also, hoping to combine g[mask], u[fill], etc into 1 function. 
// Basically any attribute that starts with "url(#"
    $(this).find("g[mask^='url']").each(function() {
     
$(this).attr("mask","url(#"+id+"-"+$(this).attr("mask").substring(5));
       });
  
   $(this).find("use[fill^='url']").each(function() {
         $(this).attr("fill","url(#"+id+"-"+$(this).attr("fill").substring(5));
       });
       
       $(this).find("use[filter^='url']").each(function() {
         $(this).attr("filter","url(#"+id+"-"+$(this).attr("filter").substring(5));
       });
    // grab data-screen value
    var data = $(this).data('screen');

    // replace this with the link inside svg
    if (data != '') {
      $(this).find("svg defs image").attr("href", data).attr("xlink:href", data);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="device" data-name="first" data-screen="image-1.png">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
    <rect id="w-circle-stroke-a" width="24" height="24"/>
    <path id="w-circle-stroke-b" d="M12,2 C17.52,2 22,6.48 22,12 C22,17.52 17.52,22 12,22 C6.48,22 2,17.52 2,12 C2,6.48 6.48,2 12,2 Z M12,3.81818182 C7.48415409,3.81818182 3.81818182,7.48415409 3.81818182,12 C3.81818182,16.5158459 7.48415409,20.1818182 12,20.1818182 C16.5158459,20.1818182 20.1818182,16.5158459 20.1818182,12 C20.1818182,7.48415409 16.5158459,3.81818182 12,3.81818182 Z M10.5553177,13.4773237 L15.155405,8.80967806 C15.5597962,8.4027095 16.222261,8.39598875 16.6350615,8.79466684 C16.6382917,8.79778661 16.6600317,8.81952282 16.7002813,8.85987545 C17.0999062,9.26113743 17.0999062,9.90402237 16.7002813,10.3052843 L10.5553177,16.5 L7.29971874,13.2228714 C6.90252847,12.8240541 6.8997633,12.1859262 7.29348277,11.7837778 L7.33224151,11.7441893 C7.73340831,11.3344341 8.39555055,11.3228774 8.8111776,11.7183766 C8.81566955,11.722651 9.39704957,12.3089667 10.5553177,13.4773237 Z"/>
    <image id="image-5" href="image-to-be-inserted.jpg"/>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <mask id="w-circle-stroke-c" fill="#fff">
      <use xlink:href="#w-circle-stroke-b"/>
    </mask>
    <g fill="#2D8EFF" mask="url(#w-circle-stroke-c)">
      <rect width="24" height="24"/>
    </g>
    <use fill="url(#pattern-4)" xlink:href="#path-3"/>
    <use fill="#000" filter="url(#filter-10)" xlink:href="#path-9"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="device" data-name="second" data-screen="image-1.png">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
    <rect id="w-circle-stroke-a" width="24" height="24"/>
    <path id="w-circle-stroke-b" d="M12,2 C17.52,2 22,6.48 22,12 C22,17.52 17.52,22 12,22 C6.48,22 2,17.52 2,12 C2,6.48 6.48,2 12,2 Z M12,3.81818182 C7.48415409,3.81818182 3.81818182,7.48415409 3.81818182,12 C3.81818182,16.5158459 7.48415409,20.1818182 12,20.1818182 C16.5158459,20.1818182 20.1818182,16.5158459 20.1818182,12 C20.1818182,7.48415409 16.5158459,3.81818182 12,3.81818182 Z M10.5553177,13.4773237 L15.155405,8.80967806 C15.5597962,8.4027095 16.222261,8.39598875 16.6350615,8.79466684 C16.6382917,8.79778661 16.6600317,8.81952282 16.7002813,8.85987545 C17.0999062,9.26113743 17.0999062,9.90402237 16.7002813,10.3052843 L10.5553177,16.5 L7.29971874,13.2228714 C6.90252847,12.8240541 6.8997633,12.1859262 7.29348277,11.7837778 L7.33224151,11.7441893 C7.73340831,11.3344341 8.39555055,11.3228774 8.8111776,11.7183766 C8.81566955,11.722651 9.39704957,12.3089667 10.5553177,13.4773237 Z"/>
    <image id="image-5" href="image-to-be-inserted.jpg"/>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <mask id="w-circle-stroke-c" fill="#fff">
      <use xlink:href="#w-circle-stroke-b"/>
    </mask>
    <g fill="#2D8EFF" mask="url(#w-circle-stroke-c)">
      <rect width="24" height="24"/>
    </g>
    <use fill="url(#pattern-4)" xlink:href="#path-3"/>
    <use fill="#000" filter="url(#filter-10)" xlink:href="#path-9"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have to use `$('.device')` when inside and you need to refer to `$(this)` and since you have 2 `each()` nested you need to pay attention to the scope of `this`.

```js
$('.device').each(function() {
   //we get the needed id using $(this) that refer to actual device
   var id = $(this).data('name');
    
  //we check all the element with ID
  $(this).find("path, rect, pattern, image, mask").each(function() {
    //now (this) refer to the actual element
    if($(this).attr("id"))
      $(this).attr("id", id+"-"+$(this).attr("id"));
  });
  //we update the <use>
   $(this).find("use").each(function() {
    //now (this) refer to the actual element
    $(this).attr("xlink:href","#"+id+"-"+$(this).attr("xlink:href").substring(1));
  });

  // grab data-screen value
  var data = $(this).data('screen');

  // replace this with the link inside svg
  if (data != '') {
    $(this).find("svg defs image").attr("href", data).attr("xlink:href", data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="device" data-screen="[[IMAGE TO USE]]" data-name="[[UNIQUE ID]]">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="635" height="420" viewBox="0 0 635 420">
    <defs>
      <path id="path-1"/>
      <rect id="path-3" />
      <pattern id="pattern-4">
        <use transform="scale(13.1875)" xlink:href="#image-5"/>
      </pattern>
      <image id="image-5" href="[[IMAGE LINK THAT IS INSERTED AFTER LOAD]]"/>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#2D8EFF" />
      <g >
        <mask id="mask-2" fill="#fff">
          <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#mask-2)">
          <mask id="mask-6" fill="#fff">
            <use xlink:href="#path-3"/>
          </mask>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! What you provided _kinda_ works. It's now properly grabbing the ID's and adding them, however, it's adding ALL the ID's to each SVG element. For example, let's say there's 3 wrapping elements, `<div class="device" data-name="first">SVG</div>` , `<div class="device" data-name="second">SVG</div>` and `data-name="third"` . This outputs `id="third-second-first-[original id]` and in that order. Even the first element has `third` first. Any thoughts here?

Comment: @randy ah  i see, you are right .. i made a mistake ! am gonna fix it

Comment: @randy it's fixed now :) i simply forget the find() ... as you need to use find() to get only the inside element unless you will get all of them

Comment: thanks! This is working perfectly now. Do you have a suggestion  on a function for an any attribute that has a value starting with `url(#`? This wasnt originally getting accounted for in your example, but I modified your code to get it to work, but, I have to create a function for each element that may have an attribute that could have a value of `url(#`. Ideally it would be nice to have a function that looks for the value regardless of element or attribute. I couldnt find a suitable answer for this one. I update my code above to show what I mean. Regardless thanks for your help!

Comment: @randy you can consider attribute selector where you can specify a kind of regex to tell that i want to search for something starting with https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp